# Importing collections breaks Meteor app deployed with mup

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mup

My Meteor app is running on a Digital Ocean droplet.

Meteor: v1.5.3
Server: Ubuntu 14.04.5 x 64

It deploys fine with mup but when I use Studio 3T to import the collections from my old 1.2 app, I see continual error messages in the console like:

```
GET http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/sockjs/info?cb=u7lbhqd_js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

GET requests for resources including images and routes are being refused. The app does run but very slowly and most images are not showing. It is not consistent; the same image will be missing, then appear when I return to the route.

I have imported the same JSON collections to my localhost version and they run perfectly.

I am connecting to the live database by forwarding the mongo instance to localhost with:

```
ssh -L 4321:localhost:27017 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

All the imported collections look fine on the live database. I can edit values in documents OK, it's only when I import an entire collection from a JSON file that it goes wrong. And I can't see why updating the collections would interfere with the GET requests.

Has anybody had a similar problem / any idea how to figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description of the problem. I would chase up the connection refused message - work out what is causing the problem - is it going to a different server, or is it being firewalled out?

Comment: I don't know how I would chase that up? I can't see how it would be going to a different server or being firewalled; that would always fail. This is intermittent. I have given up on MUP and am deploying with Passenger. MUP uses containers which seem to me like a possible point of failure and also something I can't possibly debug.

Comment: It seems strange that importing data to the database would break the app, and also strange if it is intermittent - there must be a reason somewhere. Also instead of port forwarding the database access, why don't you use an environment variable, such as `MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:password@server:port/database meteor`

Comment: It's possible that simply having more data triggers the problem, but as you say it's odd that it's intermittent. And indeed there must be a reason but there is no way I can debug MUP; the use of containers puts it beyond my ken. I've switched to deploying with Phusion Passenger which takes a bit more setup but is far more transparent and seems to work fine with Meteor 1.6 and Ubuntu 16.04. I'd be interested to know whether anybody else has managed to run MUP with that combination? As to the environment variable, I'm not sure how that would work and I don't think I have a database user set up.

Comment: The containerisation shouldn't be a problem in itself. There is very little magic to it, you can ssh into the container if you want to, or use `mup logs` to look at the console output. I would create a fresh instance and deploy to it and see if the problem is still there. Although it sounds like you have moved on already